# Graphical access to windows over ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, windows

I have a chromebook with kubuntu on and a desktop computer at home which is quite powerful running windows 10.

Since the chromebook has limited memory/hd space I would like to be able to access my LabView/Matlab/Visual Basic on the homecomputer over ssh (or another alternative if one exists).

I have tried googling for a solution but couldnt find one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "Remote Desktop Viewer" and connect using RDP protocol to windows machine (you need to allow this on windows side).

You can't do this using ssh, since windows is not running `sshd` server nor X11 client by default.

Comment: sure. You are welcome. Interoperability is sometimes painful, but RDP works really well.